# Cut first value from current list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

everybody, I'm making function that takes my custom object as an argument, then takes first argument from the list in that object, returns it and deletes it from the object. Code is:

```
(define (make-source sequence . xs)
  (let ((a (if (not (null? xs))
               xs
               (list #f))))
    (cond ((string? sequence) (append (string->list sequence) (list a)))
          ((vector? sequence) (append (vector->list sequence) (list a)))
          (else (append sequence (list a))))))

(define (next src)
  (if (equal? (car src) '(#f))
      #t
      (let ((a (car src)))
        (set! src (make-source (cdr src)))
        a)))
```

The problem is `next` returns value without changing the object.
Can you help me to fix problem?
Also, is it possible to cut element from that list without creating new one in function?

Answer (score 1):

`set!` mutates the binding and not the object the variable points to. It is the same in almost all of the programming languages of today:

```python
def f(a):
  a = 10

x = 20
f(x)
x
// => 20
```

Why isn't `x` `10` is your answer to why `next` doesn't change the object. The variable actually gets set, but it's the local variable and it stops existing in the end of the function.

The idiomatic way to program in Scheme is not to try to implement OO, but to use `map` or folds to do something with your structures. eg.

```
(define (sum-numbers lst)
  (foldl + 0 lst))

(sum-number '(1 2 3))
; ==> 6
```